# UITapGestureRecognizer & tvOS remote for Pause/Play Button

Tags: objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer, tvos, apple-tv

I am trying to create an action when a user clicks the pause/play button on the Apple TV Remote. I looked at the documentation, but the code Apple's documentation recommended does not work. Here is my code below. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Things to consider:
I am using an AVPlayerMovieController & I do have another gesture recognizer in my code but for it is a swipe gesture AND this method is getting called, just not the Pause/Play. Can someone please help?

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];  
    tap.allowedPressTypes = @[[NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPressTypePlayPause]];  
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You can override the pressesEnded method:

```
override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for press in presses {
        if(press.type == UIPressType.PlayPause) {
           // Do what you want
           // ...
        } else {
            super.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This works (without adding UITapGestureRecognizer) if your view is already detecting presses (e.g. UICollectionViewCell, etc). All else being equal, simplest solution should be the selected answer (this one).  For others you can add tap gesture recognizer with allowed press type of UIPressType.PlayPause.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/DetectingButtonPressesandGestures.html

Answer (score 3):

I've used the following, and my recogniser get's called. I think you need to get the rawValue of the PlayPause UIPressType instead of just the PlayPause UIPressType.

```
let playPauseRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "playPauseRecognizer:")
playPauseRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)]

view.addGestureRecognizer(playPauseRecognizer)
```

Comment: Did you try that with a device? It works on the simulator but not on the device.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and I found solution but to be honest I don't like it at all (but at least it is working for me).

In view did load I added

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "playPauseButtonPressed:")
    tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.PlayPause.rawValue)];
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

and I have two methods implemented:

```
    func playPauseButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.buttonPlayClicked(buttonPlay)
    print("PRESSED")
}

override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent?) {
    self.buttonPlayClicked(buttonPlay)
    print("EVENT")
}
```

I am pretty sure that I am not doing something right but I couldn't find solution anywhere. 
This is just my improvisation that works for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not working on the emulator, did you test it on the emulator or in the actual device?

Comment: I tested it on couple of devices and it was working. In simulator it worked perfectly when I implemented only tap recognizer but it didn't work on device when I tried it.

Comment: Interesting... I tested if on the actual device and it did work. Going to re install Xcode to see if its a problem with the emulator. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue where play/pause events are not working in view controllers. The workaround was to add play/pause UITapGestureRecognizer in UIWindow in appdelegate and broadcast the event using notification.